# UnknownError Speech Recognition Package

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am trying to learn Speech Recognition package, but when using this code-

```
mic = sr.Microphone()
with mic as source1:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source1)
    audihearing = r.listen(source1)
print(r.recognize_google(audihearing))
```

This code gives me following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/indo/Documents/ML/app1.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(r.recognize_google(audihearing))    
  File "/home/indo/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 858, in recognize_google
    if not isinstance(actual_result, dict) or len(actual_result.get("alternative", [])) == 0: raise UnknownValueError()
speech_recognition.UnknownValueError
```

Why is this error coming and how do I fix it?
Note: Is this coming because of Alsa Lib or something else.I am using Manjaro OS.

Comment: By looking at the speech_recognition package's [source code](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/speech_recognition/__init__.py#L860), the docstring says that it `Raises a "speech_recognition.UnknownValueError" exception if the speech is unintelligible.`

Comment: :o That means if it is not able to understand the voice, it raises this error